# Creating the NDK standalone for gcc 4.8

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, g++, cross-compiling, gcc4.8

I want to cross compile code using gcc 4.8 for Android. Running the make-standalone-toolchain.sh gives

> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (GCC) 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)

According to the documentation [1](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing) there is an option for building it for gcc 4.8

> Added APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a-hard, with additional multilib option -mfloat-abi=hard. These options are for use with ARM GCC 4.6/4.8 and clang 3.3/3.4 (which use 4.8's assembler, linker, and libs).

Currently I am using this command to generate the standalone toolchain.

> sudo sh make-standalone-toolchain.sh --verbose --ndk-dir=PATH_TO_/android-ndk-r9d --system=darwin-x86_64 –-toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 –-install-dir=PATH_TO_INSTALL_DIR

Any ideas about how to make a standalone compiler, using NDK for gcc 4.8? (I plan to use this compiler with cmake)

Thank you in advance

Comment: anybody! if this is not possible...anyone knows a gcc 4.8 compiler for Android?

Comment: I am wanting to do the same. did you ever find an answer for this?